# Unable to find suitable version for angular

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error when I run bower install for my application

Unable to find suitable version for angular

```
{
"name": "o2o",
  "homepage": "********",
  "authors": [
    "***** <****@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Online to Offline Product",
  "main": "",
  "moduleType": [],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "frontend/lib",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.3"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

change `1.5.3` to `1.5.X` in both resolutions and dependencies. it will take the latest 1.5 version.

use this json

```
 {
    "name": "o2o",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/Capillary/sharingan",
      "authors": [
        "anshulsao <anshul.sao@gmail.com>"
      ],
      "description": "Online to Offline Product",
      "main": "",
      "moduleType": [],
      "license": "MIT",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "frontend/lib",
        "test",
        "tests"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.5.x",
        "angular-route": "~1.4.9",
        "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.17",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
        "jquery": "~2.2.0",
        "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
        "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.0",
        "bourbon": "^4.2.7"
      },
      "resolutions": {
        "angular": "1.5.x"
      }
    }
```

Comment: it worked but created an another problem in API response that in data is not coming in response directly it is coming in response.data because of angular version

Comment: then i guess you need to go with 1.4 verson. replace `1.5.x` with `1.4.x` and try it